# Merging two very divergent branches using git?

Tags: git

I have my `master` branch and my `verydifferentbranch` these had the same ancestor ... about 300 commits ago. Now that `verydifferentbranch` is feature complete I'd like to put it under the master `branch`. Doing a rebase results in every single patch having a lot of merge conflicts, to the point where it would be a large project unto itself to go through all the conflicts.

I have no idea what to do except just force pushing the head of `verydifferentbranch` into `master` branch. I'd be losing all my history doing this, and that's not something I really want to do.

What are my other options?

Comment: Why don't you consider merge?

Comment: An unfortunate "you should have" non-answer: frequent merges from `master` onto `verydifferentbranch` can at least distribute the pain, assuming `verydifferentbranch` remains compatible with `master`. (If not, then the question arises why they weren't compatible throughout the development but should be now.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It sounds like your history looks like this:

```
...---o---A---o---...---o---o---B   master
           \
            o---o---...---o---C     verydifferentbranch
```

You say that you are worried about losing history if you force push `verydifferentbranch` to `master`. Such an operation would effectively be throwing away everything after `A` and up to `B`.

You can preserve the history by merging it, or just by dropping a tag at the abandoned branch tip and leaving it unmerged.

## Use a Merge

A merge would allow you to keep both sides of the history:

```
...---o---A---o---...---o---o---B
           \                     \
            o---o---...---o---C---M  master
```

The kind of merge you do will determine the content created for commit M. A normal merge (using the `recursive` merge strategy) sounds like it would produce a very large number of conflicts in your case. **If you actually need to incorporate the changes from the `A..B` commits, there is nothing else to do but work through the conflicts presented by either a merge or a rebase.** (In the future you will probably have fewer problems if you can merge or rebase more often to deal with the conflicts as they arise.) But, if you just want `M` to have the same content as `C` (i.e. you want to ignore the changes represented by the `A..B` commits), then you can use the `ours` merge strategy.

[*git-merge(1)*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) describes the `ours` merge strategy:

> This resolves any number of heads, but the resulting tree of the merge is always that of the current branch head, effectively ignoring all changes from all other branches. It is meant to be used to supersede old development history of side branches. Note that this is different from the -Xours option to the recursive merge strategy.

You can produce M with a message of `Merge commit 'abandoned/foo-features'` like this:

```
git tag -m 'describe reason for abandonment here...' \
    abandoned/foo-features master                   # tag abandoned branch tip
git checkout verydifferentbranch                    # checkout dominant branch
git branch -M verydifferentbranch master            # replace master
git merge -s ours abandoned/foo-features            # merge only other's history
git tag -d abandoned/foo-features                   # optional: delete the tag
git push wherever master tag abandoned/foo-features # publish them
```

Variations on these commands will give you slightly different automatic commit messages for `M` (you can always supply your own with `git merge -m` or amend it with `git commit --amend` afterwards).

The main point is that the resulting `master` will have both pieces of history, but none of the changes from the original `master` side (those changes are still in the history, they are just not represented in the tree referenced by commit `M`).

## Leave It Hanging

If it is acceptable to “rewrite” `master` (i.e. there is no other work based on any of the commits `A..B`, or the users involved do not mind the work it will take to [recover from the rewrite](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase)), then you could just leave a tag at the current tip of `master` and replace `master` with `verydifferentbranch`.

```
...---o---A---o---...---o---o---B   (tag: abandoned/foo-features)
           \
            o---o---...---o---C      master
```

Arrange for this like so:

```
git tag -m 'describe reason for abandonment here...' \
    abandoned/foo-features master                    # tag abandoned branch tip
git branch -M verydifferentbranch master             # replace master
git push wherever +master tag abandoned/foo-features # publish them
```

Answer (score 5):

This is why the [`git merge`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) functionality exists.

```
$> git checkout master
$> git merge verydifferentbranch
```

Odds are the first time you do this there will be a lot of conflicts (if they diverged as much as you claim). But if you keep on top of things, after the initial merge it won't be too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing a rebase first? That will likely cause issues with your changes sets since your changes sets will be looking for file versions starting from the commit where you diverged from master.

Use a git merge instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it easier to reason about and resolve merge conflicts by merging, say, every 10th commit on `verydifferentbranch` over into `master` and working through the conflicts that way.  Yes this means that you do 30 merges if you've got 300 commits, but the divergence is less significant with each of those merges by far than if you just try to merge them all at once.