# Git merge of two extremely diverged branches

Tags: git, merge

I'm volunteering to develop [SciDAVis](https://github.com/SciDAVis/scidavis), an open source application for scientific data analysis and visualization. Recently, I've found that there is a fork, [AlphaPlot](https://github.com/narunlifescience/AlphaPlot), that diverged in 2016. Using `rev-list` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31998123/12497820)) I found that AlphaPlot contains 398 commits to merge-base, SciDAVis contains 939 commits. Nasty.
I would like to reintegrate selected commits from AlphaPlot/master to SciDAVis and, if possible, to create a new merge base to simplify further reintegration. There were many renames/moves of files in Alphaplot, which is quite unpleasant for merging. I found [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568138/git-rebase-with-renamed-files), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113632/why-doesnt-git-attempt-to-merge-changes-to-renamed-files), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956300/merging-two-very-divergent-branches-using-git), [fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637678/git-how-to-merge-complex-branches-that-have-diverged-a-lot-over-the-years), [fifth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701790/git-merge-with-renamed-files) and [sixth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701790/git-merge-with-renamed-files) questions concerning the matter. Looks like I'm to use either `cherry-pick`, `merge -X rename-threshold=25` or `rebase --interactive`. The `cherry-pick` variant tells me "to set merge.renamelimit to at least 1726" and fails. Also it would not create new merge-base. `merge` variant also fails with "set merge.renamelimit to at least 1726", and `--no-ff` does not help. Of course, `rebase --interactive --strategy-option="rename-threshold=XX"` will work to some extent, but as I understand there will be no new merge-base.

 I'm okay with manual resolving of conflicts, but I'd like to avoid unnecessary work to complete merge in my lifetime. Is there any sane way to achieve merging of selected commits only and creating a new common commit as a merge-base? Thank you very much.

Comment: What is merged is a commit, not a branch. No law says to merge the branch commit. You could merge the third commit from the merge base. It might go well. Then the third commit after that. And so on. Just an idea...

Comment: Taking @matt's idea a few steps further results in [git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge).

Comment: @matt it is essentially the same as rebasing, isn't it?

Comment: @torek looks interesting, thanks!

Comment: @Suthiro I don’t see how it is in any way like rebasing.